# Android put apostrophe over cyrillic characters

Tags: android

Is there a way to put a apostrophe symbol over a Cyrillic characters inside particular TextView. For example if I have the word 'Вълна' and I want to put **`** over the **a** letter so it becomes **à** . Is there a simple way to do that in Android?

[image]

I know that I can use special UTF-8 characters that include the ` symbol à, ѝ, о̀, ѐ. But keep in mind that I want to use different fonts and some of them do not correctly display the apostrophe character. For example the word ***въ̀лна***, the letter **ъ̀**  is not properly displayed and the apostrophe appears over the letter **л**, instead of the letter **ъ**. As seen in the image below:

[image]

Is there any native 'xml' attribute that allows that?

I want to be able to set the apostrophe via ***text*** attribute. For example for the words "мѝмѐ" I would set the text value to "м`им`e", so there is way to indicate where the apostrophe should be placed. In this case to every letter directly after each apostrophe.

```
<com.slaviboy.ApostropheTextView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#41BADF"
        android:gravity="end|center"
        android:textColor="#ff00ff"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"
        android:text="В`ълната\n`е\nп`окосил`а\nцял`ото п`ле`ме"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with https://gist.github.com/slaviboy/3ff8c71bd39a20e1a95b7275018fc29b Although it is not prefect for example if the text overlaps the size of the View.

And here is the result for ApostropheTextView with the text attribute set to ***"`а `б `в `г `д `е\n`ж `з `и `й `к `л\n`м `н `о `п `р `с\n`т `у `ф `х `ц `ч\n`ш `щ `ъ `ь `ю `я\n`А `Б `В `Г `Д `Е\n`Ж `З `И `Й `К `Л\n`М `Н `О `П `Р `С\n`Т `У `Ф `Х `Ц `Ч\n`Ш `Щ `Ъ `Ь `Ю `Я"***

And here is the result that includes

1. padding
2. letterSpacing
3. lineSpacingExtra
4. gravity
5. textSize

[image]

```
<com.slaviboy.universaldictionarybg.ApostropheTextView
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="700dp"
        android:background="#1B1B1B"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:letterSpacing="0.6"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="30dp"
        android:text="`а `б `в `г `д `е\n`ж `з `и `й `к `л\n`м `н `о `п `р `с\n`т `у `ф `х `ц `ч\n`ш `щ `ъ `ь `ю `я\n`А `Б `В `Г `Д `Е\n`Ж `З `И `Й `К `Л\n`М `Н `О `П `Р `С\n`Т `У `Ф `Х `Ц `Ч\n`Ш `Щ `Ъ `Ь `Ю `Я"
        android:textColor="#6AE349"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```